# Windows Phone 8 VoIP SIP Provider

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sip, voip, windows-phone-voip

I want to develop an app with VoIP and sip. I have found a good example from Microsoft sample is [ChatterBox VoIP sample app](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b)

From this app we can receive or make audio or video call to some one.But I can not call to another number.

In this document [VoIP apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206983(v=vs.105).aspx)

the incoming call is possible through Microsoft Cloud server. It will push a notification to our phone.

I have also found some third party SIP clients for Windows Phone 8 like LinPhone and PJSIP but they are not providing how to use that thing

Now my questions are :

1) How can I integrate SIP client to this **ChatterBox** example or How can I call to another number?

2) Can it is possible to user other that Microsoft Cloud server means can I use my own server to push call to my app?

3) In **ChatterBox** example there is a default incoming call. How can I call from another to my number / my app ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

ChatterBox is just a framework for what a SIP App could be, it shows you Background Process code and also Scheduling Tasks and Push notifications.

If you want to be able to make SIP calls, you need to download the src code of a sip library like PJSIP which works very well.

Just run the code and call pjsua methods, they encapsulate the functionality quite well.